# Converting HTML + CSS text boxes in functional textboxes

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am having some problems with a project I am making. to create some good looking text boxes I used some code I found on internet.

And using C# with ASP.net

this is the code to create the textbox shape, colors and animations.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #efefef;
}

.row {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  background: #032429;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.row:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";  
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15000px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: inherit;
}
.row:first-child {
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.row span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
}

.skinny {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 215px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #377D6A;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 75px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.skinny::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #efefef;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.skinny + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 padding: 9px 15px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0.4);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skinny + label:before, .skinny + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.skinny + label:before {
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: #377D6A;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.skinny + label:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #377D6A;
}

.skinny:focus,
.skinny:active {
  color: #377D6A;
  text-indent: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.skinny:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.skinny:active::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}
.skinny:focus + label,
.skinny:active + label {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.skinny:focus + label:after,
.skinny:active + label:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

and how I show the textbox form in Default.aspx is

```
<span>
    <input class="skinny" id="wallet" type="text" placeholder="Enter name here" /><label for="wallet">Username</label>
  </span>
```

I tried to add

```
runat="server"
```

but is not working.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You mean when you try to add runat="server" this doen't work but before that it works, Don't you?

Comment: Im trying to make a login server with those buttons. 
but cant do if(textbox1=="something|| textbox2="something else"){open form 2} because the page.aspx.cs doesnt know those textfields. they are html + css textfields..

Comment: Generally also those textfields will be converted to common textfields(input texts), But there's no problem if you wana use runat="server" in input texts. Probably your ASP page and its code behind namespace or class inheritance is didn't set correct.

Comment: thats the problem I'm facing. I can type on those textboxes. but i cant get the value of them. thats the problem